# JavaScript - A tags disable onClick, enable onClick on Tags (Modal-Pop up)

Tags: javascript, onclick, modal-dialog

I have several "a" tags that contain the attribute "onclick". When I click on one of them. They display an image and a modal(pop up). I am aiming to disable the rest of the "a" tags so I do not have other modal windows appearing if I click on other "a" tags.

I created the following code. I  managed to do the first part but it does not work to enable all the "a" attributes once the modal is closed.  Do you know why is it?

```
function toggleModal(modalId, toggle, bgImageId) {
    var icons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var toytownImage = document.querySelector("#toytownImage");
    var bgImage = document.getElementById(bgImageId);
    var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    ////////
    toytownImage.style.display = "none";
    if (toggle) {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      //Appear another image
      bgImage.style.display = "block";
      //This block the icons to be clicked
      for (var i=0; i < icons.length; i++) icons[i].onclick = null;
    } else {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      bgImage.style.display = "none";
      toytownImage.style.display = "block";
      //Allows icons to click again
      for (var i=0; i < icons.length; i++) icons[i].onclick = toggle;
      //alert(toggle);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi, It is here:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shnagalindo/fv0w5by8/75/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable outside of the function and set that variable with the modalId when the function is called. On the function calls after that you can check if another modalId has been toggled and prevent toggling if the modalId in the variable is still set to display block. For example:

```
var active_modal;

function toggleModal(modalId, toggle, bgImageId) {
   if(!active_modal) {
      active_modal = modalId;
   } 
   var current_modal = document.getElementById(active_modal);
   if(current_modal.style.display !== 'block') {
      active_modal = modalId;
      //code is only executed when the current_modal is not displayed anymore
   } 
}
```

I've updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fv0w5by8/116/. Note that I moved the displays to each div instead of the .modal class. The other changes have been made to the toggleModal function itself.